# appengine, python: Is there a memory leak in taskqueue.add()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-leaks

The following code adds tasks that perform some processing on files from the blobstore, it runs on a B2 **backend** so it has no timeout limit:

```
for task in tasks:
    tools.debug("add_tasks_to_process_files", "adding_task")

    taskqueue.add(\
            name=("Process_%s_files---%s--%s--%s--%s" % \
                        (len(tasks[task]), task[1], task[0], task[2], int(time.time()))),\
            queue_name="files-processor",\
            url="/analytics/process_files/",\
            params={"processing_task": json.dumps({"profile": task, "blobs_to_process": tasks[task]})})
```

tasks is a dictionary in the following form:

```
{
    (x1,y1,z1): ["blob_key", "blob_key"... (limited to 35 keys)],
    (x2,y2,z2): ["blob_key", "blob_key"...],
    .
    .
    .
}
```

x1, y1, z1 are all strings

tools.debug is a function I wrote that sends messages to my local sever using urlfetch (so I won't have to wait 20min to be able to read the logs):

```
def debug(location, message, params=None, force=False):
    if not (settings.REMOTE_DEBUG or settings.LOCALE_DEBUG or force):
        return

    if params is None:
        params = {}

    params["memory"] = runtime.memory_usage().current()
    params["instance_id"] = settings.INSTANCE_ID

    debug_message = "%s/%s?%s" % (urllib2.quote(location), urllib2.quote(message), "&".join(["%s=%s" % (p, urllib2.quote(unicode(params[p]).encode("utf-8"))) for p in params]))

    if settings.REMOTE_DEBUG or force:
        fetch("%s/%s" % (settings.REMOTE_DEBUGGER, debug_message))

    if settings.LOCALE_DEBUG or force:
        logging.debug(debug_message)
```

since tools.debug wasn't in the code when it first failed, I know for sure it isn't the cause for the memory problems.

I got this error:

```
   /add_tasks_to_process_files/ 500 98812ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine):
    A serious problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application. (Error code 201)
```

And right after it:

```
/_ah/stop 500 110ms 0kb
Exceeded soft private memory limit with 283.406 MB after servicing 1 requests total
```

again, I received it for the code above without the line: `tools.debug("add_tasks_to_process_files", "adding_task")`

Now, let me show you what I see in my debugger:

```
1 2012-1-19 14:41:38 [processors-backend] processors-backend-initiated instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 18.05078125, backend_instance_url: http://0.processors.razoss-dock-dev.appspot.com, backend_load_balancer_url: http://processors.razoss-dock-dev.appspot.com
2 2012-1-19 14:41:39 [AddTasksToProcessFiles] start instance_id: 1329662498, files_sent_to_processing_already_in_previous_failed_attempts: 0, memory: 19.3828125
3 2012-1-19 14:41:59 [AddTasksToProcessFiles] add_tasks_to_process_files-LOOP_END total_tasks_to_add: 9180, total_files_added_to_tasks: 9184, task_monitor.files_sent_to_processing: 0, total_files_on_tasks_dict: 9184, instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 56.52734375
4 2012-1-19 14:42:0 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 57.81640625
5 2012-1-19 14:42:0 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 57.81640625
6 2012-1-19 14:42:1 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 57.9375
7 2012-1-19 14:42:2 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 57.9375
8 2012-1-19 14:42:2 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 58.03125
.
.
.
2183 2012-1-19 14:53:45 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 280.66015625
2184 2012-1-19 14:53:45 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 280.66015625
2185 2012-1-19 14:53:45 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 281.0
2    186 2012-1-19 14:53:46 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 281.0
2187 2012-1-19 14:53:46 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 281.0
2188 2012-1-19 14:53:46 [add_tasks_to_process_files] adding_task instance_id: 1329662498, memory: 281.3828125
```

full trace: http://pastebin.com/CcPDU6s7

Is there a memory leak in taskqueue.add() ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you evaluate memory usage?

Comment: Do you have similar memory usage pattern if you remove blobstore api call from your tasks?

Comment: Hi proppy: I've found the cause: the appstats was enabled ... thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this doesn't answer your particular question, have you tried `Queue` to add tasks in batches?

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queues.html#Queue_add

You can add up to 100 tasks at once.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Quotas_and_Limits_for_Push_Queues

Untested code.

```
queue = taskqueue.Queue(name="files-processor")
while tasks:
    queue.add(taskqueue.Task(...) for k,v in (tasks.popitem() for _ in range(min(len(tasks),100))))
```

If you still want to use `tasks` elsewhere you'd have to change this construct slightly (or make a copy).

Comment: Replacing the original code with this solved the problem for us (It is now works for the max load we want to support). Might be because of less calls to queue.add . I didn't try to see whether sending x100 more tasks will cause the original problem: lack of time, and we don't plan our loads to produce this amount of tasks... thanks a lot!

Comment: And, a question: is there a reason you decided to use range() instead of xrange()?

Comment: @theosp: To be honest, I was expecting that question :) With such small lists there is practically no difference, but you're right, xrange is another mini-improvement. Great it worked for you!